# Is possible to do bypass to VPN with Certificate?

Tags: certificates, vpn

I would like to know if there is a way to make a false certificate to bypass a Palo Alto VPN (specifically Global-Protect). The clients only connect by certificate and I don't know if some hacker can create a false certificate and connect to my vpn. I want to emphasize that with the legitimate certificate, they are already inside my network.

I would like to know if there is another way to bypass or hack it, just connect through the Global-Protect agent and disable the web access.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If it were possible, this would be a huge vulnerability and it would probably need to be patched immediately, so it is unlikely that this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst conceptually it is possible to brute force certificate keys, this is deemed hugely impractical to execute within a reasonable time frame.

Assuming you have a secure configuration (i.e. RSA keys > 2048 bits or an EC of 256 bits or more) this is not a viable attack vector.

That isn't to say that because you don't have additional authentication factors, a legitimate user's connection profile could be stolen (either targeted or incidentally) and a connection made on their behalf.

Comment: and "reasonable time frame" means "before the Sun turns into a supernova and life on Earth is vaporized."

Comment: Of course, the definition of unreasonable is subjective, though that is a good piece of info to help make a call ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, a hacker cannot create a false certificate and connect.

But the hacker can create a valid certificate, using the server infrastructure to do so. He needs to get internal access to the administration console and issue a certificate for him, just like the administration creates a certificate for their internal clients. It would be an unauthorized certificate, but a valid one.

Bruteforcing even a 128-bit certificate is currently not possible with today's technology. In a century or two it may be possible to bruteforce a 128-bit certificate in less than a human lifetime. But not today.

A 256-bit certificate would take billions of years, at least.